# Is is possible that $A \times C$ homeomorphic to $B \times C$?

Tags: general-topology

> Suppose that $A$ and $B$ are non-homeomorphic subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ and $C$ is a subset of $\mathbb{R}$. Is it possible that $A \times C$ is homeomorphic to $B \times C$?

I'm not even sure if its possible or not, so I have no idea what a counterexample would even be. Any ideas?

Comment: Well $A\times\emptyset$ is homeomorphic to $B\times\emptyset$.

Comment: Also if $\mathcal{C}$ is the Cantor set, $\{ 0 \} \times \mathcal{C} \cong \mathcal{C} \times \mathcal{C}$.

Comment: Maybe a bit easier: $\{1\} \times \mathbb{Z} \cong \{1,2\} \times \mathbb{Z} \cong \{1,2,3\} \times \mathbb{Z} \cong \ldots \cong \mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}.$

Answer (score 6):

$[0,1) \times [0,1)$ is homeomorphic to $[0,1] \times [0,1)$ and $[0,1)$ is not homeomorphic to $[0,1]$. So it is indeed possible with subsets of $\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 2):

Yes — as Adayah has pointed out,

If $A = \{0\}$ is a singleton set, and $B = C = \mathfrak{C}$, the Cantor set, then

$$A \not\cong B \qquad A\times C =\mathfrak{C}  \qquad B\times C = \mathfrak{C}^2$$

and $\mathfrak{C}$ is homeomorphic to $\mathfrak{C}^2$ via the map that “unzips” the ternary representation:

$$\langle a_1b_1a_2b_2 \ldots \rangle \mapsto \langle a_1a_2a_3\ldots\rangle\times \langle b_1b_2b_3\ldots\rangle $$

Comment: Or because both spaces are compact zero-dimensional metric spaces without isolated points, hence homeomorphic, by Brouwer's theorem.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible? **Yes.**

> Let $A=(0,1),B=[0,1]$ and $C=\emptyset$. Then $A$ and $B$ are not homeomorphic as $A $ is not compact, but $B$ is. Further, $$A \times C=B\times C$$Thus, $A \times C$ is homeomphic to $B \times C.$

Is it always true? **No.**

> Let $A=\{0\},B=\mathbb R$ and $C=\mathbb R.$ Then Then $A$ and $B$ are not homeomorphic as $B$ is not compact, but $A$ is.
>   Further, $A \times C$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb R$ and $B \times C$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb R^2.$